# How to unmarshal XML file that contains mixed tag (has attributes, and has content value with nested tag) with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need to convert xml file to java objects.

```xml
<PRODUCT id="10" name="Notebook">
    <VALUE id="30" type="Formatted">This is mixed <TUNIT style="style-12">formatted</TUNIT> text value.</VALUE>
</PRODUCT>
```

Here is Product class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "PRODUCT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElementRef(name = "VALUE")
    private Value value;
}
```

Here is Value class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "VALUE")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Value {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlValue
    private String content;

    @XmlElementRef(name = "TUNIT")
    private Tunit tunit;
}
```

Here is Tunit class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "TUNIT")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tunit {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "style")
    private String style;

    @XmlValue
    private String content;
}
```

When I set @XmlAttribute for `<VALUE>` attribute id, @XmlValue for `<VALUE>` content, and @XmlElementRef for `<TUNIT>` - I'm getting an error:

`If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.`

Is it possible to unmarshal this xml with JAXB?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65938694/edit) your question and add the Java classes corresponding to the `PRODUCT` and `VALUE` elements?

Comment: Ok. I have edited my question and added java classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your `<VALUE ...>...</VALUE>` element you have mixed content:
plain text and a `<TUNIT>` element.

Therefore, in your `Value` class you need to define a `List<Object>` property
to receive this mixed content (in your case strings and objects
of type `Tunit`.
For this to happen you need to annotate it with `@XmlMixed`
and also with `@XmlElementRef` (to define the
mapping between XML `<TUNIT>` and Java `Tunit`).
See also the example in the [API documentation of `@XmlMixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlMixed.html).

For your XML example with the XML fragment
`This is mixed <TUNIT style="style-12">formatted</TUNIT> text value.`
the mixed content list in the `Value` object will receive
these items:

- a string `"This is mixed "`
- a `Tunit` object
- a string `" text value."`

So finally the `Value` class will look like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "VALUE")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Value {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlElementRef(name = "TUNIT", type = Tunit.class)
    private List<Object> content;
}
```